# Passing arrays and pointers with access violation

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am working on an assignment which must pass pointers for all function 
parameters. No global variables are allowed except global constants.

I'm to create an array of "bids" in main and fill it with readBids() function. This works, but I am then supposed to pass it to a function to bubble sort it. My program breaks once my sortBids function is called. I'm learning pointers now and I can't see what I am doing wrong. The Call Stack gives `Project4.exe!main()Line32`, which points to `sortBids(bidArray, numBids);`

Any help and an explanation would be very appreciated.

```
 #include <iostream>
    #include <string>

    using namespace std;

    string* readProductName();
    int* readNumBids();
    double* readBids(string,int);
    void sortBids(double*, int*);
    void averageBid();
    void maxBid();
    void totalBid();
    void printReport();


    int main(){
        string* productName;
        int* numBids;


        productName = readProductName();
        numBids = readNumBids();
        double* bidArray = readBids(*productName, *numBids);
        sortBids(bidArray, numBids);


        cout << *productName << " " << *numBids << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < *numBids; i++){
            cout << bidArray[i] << endl;
        }
        system("PAUSE");
        delete productName;
        delete numBids;
        delete bidArray;
        return 0;
    }

    string* readProductName(){
        string* productName = new string;
        cout << "\n Please enter a product name\n";
        cin >> *productName;

        return productName;
    }

    int* readNumBids(){
        int* numBids = new int;
        cout << "\n Please enter the number of bids\n";
        cin >> *numBids;

        return numBids;

    }

    double* readBids(string productName, int numBids){
        int* size = new int;
        size = &numBids;
        string* productNamePtr = new string;
        productNamePtr = &productName;

        double *bidArray;
        bidArray = new double[*size];

        cout << "\nHow many bids for the " << *productNamePtr << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < *size; i++){
            cout << "Please enter bid #" << i + 1 << endl;
            cin >> bidArray[i];
            if (bidArray[i] <= 0){
                cout << "\nPlease enter an amount larger than 0\n";
                i--;
            }
        }
    return bidArray;
}

void sortBids(double* array, int *size){
    bool* swap = bool{ false };
    double* temp = new double;

    do
    {
        *swap = false;
        for (int count = 0; count < *size - 1; count++)
        {
            if (array[count] > array[count + 1])
            {
                *temp = array[count];
                array[count] = array[count + 1];
                array[count + 1] = *temp;
                *swap = true;
            }
        }
    } while (*swap);
}
```

Comment: You have seen too much Java and too little C++. `new double;` and such is madness.

Comment: **must pass pointers for all function parameters** why on Earth?

Comment: @LogicStuff, new double is madness even in Java :)

Comment: @SergeyA  it's an exercise on pointers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:**

You intialise `swap` to 0.  As `swap` is a pointer to `bool`, you have a null pointer.

You later dereference this pointer without ever having it point to a valid bool object:

```
   *swap = true;
```

Tha is UB and this is why you get an access violation !

**Solution**

Either you define this variable as plain object `bool swap = false;` and use swap everywhere.  Or you initialize it correctly `bool *swap = new bool{false};` and you use `*swap` everywhere.

**Miscellaneous advice:**

Attention: bidArray is allocated with `new[]`, so you have to `delete[]` it or risk undefined behaviour !

In pointer definitions, take the habit of puting the star next to the variable and not to the type.  Why ? Because optically it is confusing:

```
 bool* a,b;   // defines a pointer to bool a, but a PLAIN BOOL b ! 
 bool  *a,b;  // invites otpically to right interpretation by human reader
```

Comment: Just one more reason for the OP to get rid of all the pointers

Comment: I corrected this but it doesn't solve my original problem.  @NathanOliver I would love to get rid of the pointers but it is a requirement of the assignment.

Comment: @sircrisp What is this assignment supposed to teach you? To hate C++?

Comment: @LogicStuff the difference between an object and its address ?  Not to forget *  ?  avoid nullptr ? or all together ;-)

Comment: @Christophe But not on primitive types, please.

Comment: I've made the necessary changes, but the program still breaks at the same point with the same call stack message.

Comment: What's not clear to me is what you have after the ending brace of `sortBids()` : count is no longer defined outside the for loop, and there seems to be a mismatch in your brace count.

Comment: I must have accidentally pasted into it when making edits, I've corrected it, still hoping for a solution.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error neither on this [livedemo](http://ideone.com/UMk0D0) nor on MSVC2015.  Can you give the input sequence that you use to make it crash ?  (and are you sure that you compiled properly and not accidentally run the last compiled version ?)

Comment: Definitely not running on last compiled version. I'm on visual studio community 2013 , not sure what you mean by input sequence.

Comment: I mean:  "What do you type in when executing the programme ?" so that I can try the same example

Comment: "screwdriver"  "3"  "1.52" "2.13"  "1.10"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103239/discussion-between-christophe-and-sircrisp).